Robosense RS-LiDAR-M1 AN2 Interface Box
I'm interested in buying a used Robosense RS-LiDAR-M1, and found used models discounted to the \\$500 to \\\$700 dollar range (from \\\\$8,000 new). However, according to the Robosense User Manual page 16, there's an AN2 interface box that connects between the LIDAR and ethernet, which are not mentioned by the online listings I have seen.
I've been trying to find out any information on AN2 connections, or anywhere that sells the breakout box without the LIDAR, with no success.
Is this connection proprietary and not sold separately from the LIDAR or am I just looking in the wrong places?

I've used exactly the same product before.
I purchased 2 sensors, the same M1, but the interface box was different depending on the time of purchase.
One was made of metal, and one was made of plastic. Connectors were also different (AN1 version, AN2 version).
Maybe there are a number of minor changes. If you have an interface box different from the picture in the manual attached to the package you want to buy, you can use it.
If not, as I know there is no place to sell separately.
Therefore, it is recommended to ask the Robosense directly if they can provide an interface box for your sensor.
